# Internal messaging in SharePoint

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, feature, site-template

Are there any built-in templates/features in WSS3.0/MOSS 2007 that provide internal messaging functionality?

Not email integration -- I'm thinking of the kind of internal messaging between members that you get in a site such as Facebook, for example.

If something like that is not built-in, are there any 3rd party solutions you know of?  Or would it be quite simple to roll your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Zevenseas *Team Status Site*: http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Daniel/archive/2009/04/28/taking-assembly-free-solutions-to-the-next-next-level-team-status-site-twitter.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Newgator has some software that supported these concepts in 2007.  I would be reluctant to purchase or build anything custom for 2007 unless you know that it will be years before you can implement 2010 which has many of these features available in the Server version.